# How to add path to UIImage which will remove pixels?

Tags: ios, uiimage, uibezierpath

I have UIImage with some image.

And i have UIBezierPath (user signature).

How to make what path erase pixels in UIImage for alpha.

Simply like scratch some uiimage?

i try

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, YES, 0.0);
    [[UIColor clearColor] setStroke];

    [self.blurImageView.image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];
    CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGBlendModeClear);
    [self.path stroke];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    self.blurImageView.image = img;
```

But it just draw black line.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing `YES` into the `opaque` parameter of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. Therefore instead of creating transparency, `kCGBlendModeClear` will fill with black (as there's no alpha channel to clear).

The fix is to use a non-opaque context.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
```